# How to remove imageView from tableview's cell, and reset the cell's height

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, tableview

I use auto layout and constraints in my custom cell, which include imageView,`UILabel`, and the `UILabel` can auto adjust the content height(I use`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`).

Now i want to remove cell's`imageView` in demo(i set`imageView` nil), i can do that, but i can't change the cell's height small.What should i do, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried reload cell at index path?

Comment: How are you removing the imageView? Are you changing its frame?

Comment: @UtsavParikh i set imageview equal nil

Answer (score 0):

You can override the UITableView function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65.0
}
```

Comment: i’m afraid i can't use this, because my label's height can't fix

Comment: But You can put a condition to return differents values